# Foursquare Check-in Feed Location

Tags: android, gps, foursquare, checkin

I just checked the feeds automatically generated by Foursquare. When viewing the KML in Google Maps it appears the pins on the map are the location of my phone (or where it thinks my phone is) and not the location of the place I checked in at.

My phone has a pretty crappy GPS and it usually thinks I'm in the middle of the ocean or nowhere near where I'm checking in. *This often makes checking in very hard!! :(*

**Is it possible to get the pins of the checked-in location instead of my phone?**

Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed the check-in history page shows the new MapBox map which does pin the real locations. Is there a way to tap into this?

Answer (score 0):

The locations returned by our APIs/feeds should always be the locations of the venue, not your reported location. If you're convinced otherwise, e-mail api@foursquare.com with more details (like the check-in ids and the data you're receiving about those check-ins)